# Finite Mean and Finite Variance

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable. Suppose there exists a constant $c ∈ R$ such that $E(|X − c|^2) < ∞$. Show that the random variable $X$ has finite mean and variance.

And I'm quite confused about the definition about finite mean and variance. I searched on google, but seems there is no explanation in datail. Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: 1) Kindly use the self-study tag. 2) Do you know the integral (or sum) definitions of population mean and population variance?

Comment: Search for [infinite mean variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=infinite+mean+variance) for many discussions and examples.  The first duplicate addresses your confusion. The second duplicate answers the question about finite variance.  The third duplicate answers the question about finite mean.